# Default Selector Timeout in TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have an integration test which calls TestCafe's .click() method:

```
public async clickOnSomething() {
    await t
        .click(this.something);
}
```

A member of my team asked whether we should use a timeout here. TestCafe's documentation states: "Before executing an action, TestCafe waits for the target element to appear in the DOM and become visible. If this does not happen within the selector timeout, the test fails."

We have not set a selector timeout. My question is: is there some default timeout here or will the test wait ad inifinitum? How does this work exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default [selectorTimeout](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/configuration-file.html#selectortimeout) is set to 10 seconds and it can be over ridden by mentioning a timeout in the [options](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements.html#selector-timeout) or the timeout specified in the `runner.run` API method or the `--selector-timeout` command line option